# Acting with a quantum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I have a very basic question that might sound silly. But I have noticed that in some cases when we act with a quantum operator, say $\hat{A}$ on some state, say $\rho$, we sometimes just write: \begin{equation} \hat{A}\rho. \end{equation} But in some other cases we write $$\hat{A} \rho \hat{A}^\dagger.$$

How do I know when to use which case?

I am not entirely sure what the second case even mean. Any clarification on this matter would be highly appreciated. If this is very basic stuff, feel free to point me in a direction where I can learn more about it. I have not found any satisfying answer.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide some references where you've seen the one or the other.

Comment: Consider $|\psi\rangle$ in the first case and $|\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$ in the second.

Comment: Normally one does not use ρ for a state. One uses it for a density matrix (operator). Using the same symbol for two different objects unleashes well-deserved confusion.